# do you follow any particular patterns for your joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Do you follow any particular patterns for your joins?  For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM x
JOIN y ON y.Id = x.Id
```

In the example above, the table specified immediately after the JOIN keyword is the first table specified after the ON keyword. And then this pattern can be used consistently for the rest of the joins. Do you use this pattern or a similar pattern?  Do you follow any other particular patterns for your joins?

Comment: What difference would it make, even if we write x.Id = y.Id it will have same set of matching rows.

Comment: You should be consistent.  I do it in that order.

Comment: I also explicitly qualify my joins... I never use just "JOIN"... I use "INNER JOIN", "LEFT OUTER JOIN", "RIGHT OUTER JOIN", "CROSS JOIN", etc. Always be explicit.

Comment: There's no set rule for that. Unless your company/team has some coding house rules for that.  Personally I prefere always starting the ON with the field of the joined table. To me it looks better when having multiple joins.

Answer (score 1):

I like y first as it will (should be in all)

```
SELECT *
FROM x
JOIN y  ON y.Id = x.Id 
JOIN z  ON z.Id = y.zID 
       AND z.dt < x.dt
```